# Combining 2 regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have 2 strings and I would like to get a result that gives me everything before the first '\n\n'.

'1. melléklet a 37/2018. (XI. 13.) MNB rendelethez\n\nÁltalános kitöltési előírások\nI.\nA felügyeleti jelentésre vonatkozó általános szabályok\n\n1.

'12. melléklet a 40/2018. (XI. 14.) MNB rendelethez\n\nÁltalános kitöltési előírások\n\nKapcsolódó jogszabályok\naz Önkéntes Kölcsönös Biztosító Pénztárakról szóló 1993. évi XCVI. törvény (a továbbiakban: Öpt.);\na személyi jövedelemadóról szóló 1995. évi CXVII.

I have been trying to combine 2 regular expressions to solve my problem; however, I could be on a bad track either. Maybe a function could be easier, I do not know.

I am attaching one that says that I am finding the character 'z'

```py
extended regex : [\z+$]
I guess finding the first number is: [^0-9.].+
```

My problem is how to combine these two expressions to get the string inbetween them?

Is there a more efficient way to do?

Comment: Try `re.findall(r'^(\d.*?)(?:\n\n|$)', s, re.S)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are a genius!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.findall(r'^(\d.*?)(?:\n\n|$)', s, re.S)
```

Or with `re.search`, since it seems that only one match is expected:

```
m = re.search(r'^(\d.*?)(?:\n\n|$)', s, re.S)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HUhrLV).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of  a string
- `(\d.*?)` - Capturing group 1: a digit and then any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?:\n\n|$)` - a non-capturing group matching either two newlines or end of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%5Cd.*%3F)(%3F%3A%5Cn%5Cn%7C%24)):

[image]